# ClientCustomSSL with HTTP 4.1.1

Tags: java, https, httpclient, keystore, apache-httpclient-4.x

Can anybody tell me whether we have to create my.keystore file or it will be created. And when I created this file in the same directory(webapp directory) where my jsp file is and I am using this code in my jsp file.

```
KeyStore trustStore  = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());        
FileInputStream instream = new FileInputStream(new File("my.keystore")); 
try {
    trustStore.load(instream, "nopassword".toCharArray());
} finally {
    instream.close();
}

SSLSocketFactory socketFactory = new SSLSocketFactory(trustStore);
Scheme sch = new Scheme("https", socketFactory, 443);
httpclient.getConnectionManager().getSchemeRegistry().register(sch);
```

And I got the error

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: my.keystore (The system cannot find the file spec
ified)
```

So where should I put this file. this is the path for both of the file, that jsp file and my.keystore

```
C:\workspace\search-ui\search-ui\src\main\webapp
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend adding the keystore to the classpath and then load it via

```
InputStream instream = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("my.keystore");
```

Putting the keystore under webapp but not under WEB-INF is insecure since anyone could just download it. Also, loading a file via `new File()` looks in the working directory for the Java process when a relative file path is used (see the [JavaDoc](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html)). This is most likely somewhere under the directory hierarchy of the Servlet container you are using.

Comment: so I have created the blank file with the name my.keystore. is that right?

Comment: If you plan on loading it in that call to `trustStore.load` it will need to contain a valid Java keystore.

Comment: so how I can do that.. I don't understand actually.. :(

Comment: I think you should study a tutorial such as this http://www.techbrainwave.com/?p=953 Why are you trying to replace the truststore?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a keystore at all unless your server requires client authentication. Does it?